# Why whole TabBar not working when added to scaffold body?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to add TabBar in body, inside a Container but an error seems to come.

ERROR:
`RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.`

Code:

```
 Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              child: DefaultTabController(
                  length: 3,
                  child: Row(children: [
                    TabBar(
                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.redAccent,
                        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                        indicator: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            color: Colors.redAccent),
                        tabs: [
                          Tab(
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1)),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Text("APPS"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1)),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Text("MOVIES"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1)),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Text("GAMES"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]),
                    TabBarView(children: [
                      Icon(Icons.apps),
                      Icon(Icons.movie),
                      Icon(Icons.games),
                    ])
                  ])),
            )
```

As, you can see I have `DefaultTabController` inside child of container, having a row where first is `TabBar` and second is `TabBarView`.

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Also, I know the usual convention is to have tabbar in a appbar. but that doesn't work with my design. Even if I have to add tabbar in appbar then I have to increase the height of appbar as per my design which is why opted for this kind of approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace Row with Column

```
DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          child: Column(children: [ // Column Here
```

Wrap TabBarView with Expanded

```
Expanded(
  child: TabBarView(children: [
    Icon(Icons.apps),
    Icon(Icons.movie),
    Icon(Icons.games),
  ]),
)
```

Comment: Yes, this worked but had to specify the height of the container.
`Container(
              height: 200,`
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the TabBar to the appbar field in the Scaffold, as this:

```
Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Tabbed AppBar'),
            bottom: TabBar(
                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.redAccent,
                        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                        indicator: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            color: Colors.redAccent),
                        tabs: [
                          Tab(
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1)),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Text("APPS"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1)),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Text("MOVIES"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1)),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Text("GAMES"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
          ),
```

Comment: This i know but, isn't it possible to add tabbar in body rather than appbar bottom?